# Need help in 3 tier entity class object code

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to access entity class but getting the error message "No overload method for CreateDoctor takse 3 argument" Here is my code please modify somebody..
DoctorProperty class:

```
public class DoctorProperty //class for doctor table
{
    int _Id;
    string _Name;
    string _Address;
    int _Phone;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _Address;
        }
        set
        {
            _Address = value;
        }
    }
    public int Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return _Phone;
        }
        set
        {
            _Phone = value;
        }
    }
}
Doctor DataLayer:
public class DoctorDataLayer
{
    public string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    public int AddDoctor(DoctorProperty obj)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);             
        SqlCommand com =new SqlCommand("insert into Doctor values('"+obj.Name+"','"+obj.Address+"','"+obj.Phone+"')",con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return 0;    
    }
}
Doctor BusinessLayer:
public class DoctorBusinessLayer
{   
    public void CreateDoctor(DoctorProperty obj)
    {
        DoctorDataLayer dl = new DoctorDataLayer();
        dl.AddDoctor(obj);    
    }
}
AdDoctor.aspx.cs
protected void Btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoctorBusinessLayer DB = new DoctorBusinessLayer();
        DoctorProperty dp = new DoctorProperty();
        DB.CreateDoctor(TxtName.Text, TxtAddress.Text, TxtPhone.Text);
    }
```

Above highlighted line getting error:

Comment: You need to reformat the code in your question so that it's readable before anyone has a chance of helping you!

Answer (score 0):

Your CreateDoctor method only take 1 argument.

```
public void CreateDoctor(DoctorProperty)
```

But you're calling it with 3 arguments...

```
DB.CreateDoctor(string, string, string)
```

You could solve the problem in 1 way...

Edit:
Taking a closer look at your code it seems it would benefit of a rewrite, so here goes:

```
public class Doctor
{
  // JohannesH: Changed to use auto properties instead.
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public static class DoctorDataLayer
{
  public static void AddDoctor(Doctor doctor) // JohannesH: Changed return type from int to void.
  {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; // JohannesH: Changed from .ToString() to .ConnectionString

    // JohannesH: Changed to use "using" to make sure everything gets disposed correctly during failure.
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      using (var command = new  SqlCommand("insert into doctor values(@name,@address,@phone)", connection))
      {
        // JohannesH: Now using SqlParameters to get rid of sql injection attacks.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", doctor.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", doctor.Address);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", doctor.Phone);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}

public static class DoctorBusinessLayer
{
  public static void CreateDoctor(string name, string address, string phone) 
  {
    DoctorDataLayer.AddDoctor(new Doctor {Name = name, Address = address, Phone = phone});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
DB.CreateDoctor(TxtName.Text, TxtAddress.Text, TxtPhone.Text);
```

With these :

```
dp.Name = TxtName.Text;
dp.Address = TxtAddress.Text;
dp.Phone = TxtPhone.Text;
DB.CreateDoctor(db);
```

Here is the reformatted code :

```
DoctorProperty class: public class DoctorProperty //class for doctor table 
{ 
int _Id; 
string _Name; 
string _Address; 
int _Phone; 

public int Id { get { return _Id; } set { _Id = value; } } 
public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } } 
public string Address { get { return _Address; } set { _Address = value; } } 
public int Phone { get { return _Phone; } set { _Phone = value; } } 
} 

//Doctor DataLayer: 

public class DoctorDataLayer 
{ 
public string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString(); 

public int AddDoctor(DoctorProperty obj) 
{ 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
SqlCommand com =new SqlCommand("insert into Doctor values('"+obj.Name+"','"+obj.Address+"','"+obj.Phone+"')",con); 
com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
return 0;
} 
} 

//Doctor BusinessLayer: 

public class DoctorBusinessLayer {
public void CreateDoctor(DoctorProperty obj) 
{ 
DoctorDataLayer dl = new DoctorDataLayer(); 
dl.AddDoctor(obj);
} 
} 

//AdDoctor.aspx.cs 

protected void Btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
DoctorBusinessLayer DB = new DoctorBusinessLayer(); 
DoctorProperty dp = new DoctorProperty(); 
dp.Name = TxtName.Text;
dp.Address = TxtAddress.Text;
dp.Phone = TxtPhone.Text;
DB.CreateDoctor(db); 
}
```

Comment: In his code, "DoctorProperty.Phone" is an int, so at least you have to convert the string (although it seems like it is a string in the db). And please just put a small note about the sql injection vulnerability... I mean, concatenating a sql statement with text values directly from a textbox?! ;)